# Find first sign change in a list

Tags: python

I have a list, A, of integers of such that:

1. len(A) ≥ 2
2. The first and last elements of A have different signs
3. All the elements of A are non-zero

I need to write a function that detects the first sign change beside the first and last elements and where O(log n). Is it possible?

```
def myFunction(A,begin):
    if(begin >= len(A)):
        return [A[0],A[len(A)-1]]
    if(A[begin]>0):
        if(A[begin+1]>0):
            return myFunction(A,begin+1)
        else:
            return [A[begin],A[begin+1]]
    else:
        if (A[begin + 1] < 0):
            return myFunction(A, begin + 1)
        else:
            return [A[begin], A[begin + 1]]
```

Comment: Two questions. What code have you tried? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: @chepner does it matter?

Comment: To determine if this can be done in O(log n), I believe it does.

Comment: Oh yeah, right.

Comment: def myFunction(A,begin):
    if(begin >= len(A)):
        return [A[0],A[len(A)-1]]
    if(A[begin]>0):
        if(A[begin+1]>0):
            return myFunction(A,begin+1)
        else:
            return [A[begin],A[begin+1]]
    else:
        if (A[begin + 1] < 0):
            return myFunction(A, begin + 1)
        else:
            return [A[begin], A[begin + 1]]

Comment: i tried this and no the list isnt sorted

Comment: @Raja please include the code with propper formatting (intendation) by editing your question.

Comment: Please see the guidelines on posting to stack overflow. You should put your formatted code in your original question. Also, if the list isn't sorted, is there at least only 1 sign change in the list? or are there multiple? For example, ```[ -2, -1, 1, 2]`` has one sign change and ```[-2, 1, -3, 2, -4, 5]``` has 5.

Comment: yes there are multiple i need to find  the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is O(log N), because it compares the first element with the middle element, and then continues with only the first or second half of the list. However, this does only work if there is only a **single** sign change.

```
def find_sign_change(A):
    if len(A) == 2:
        return 1
    i = len(A) // 2
    if A[0] * A[i] < 0:
        # different sign
        return find_sign_change(A[:i+1])
    else:
        # same sign
        return find_sign_change(A[i:]) + i


print(find_sign_change([3, 4, 6,-6,-5,-3,-5]))
>>> 3
print(find_sign_change([3,-4, 6, 6, 5, 3,-5]))
>>> 6
```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski yes, this is intended to demonstrate the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about something like this for `O(log N)`
(Not sure if it's exactly `O(log N)` - but it definitely always works ;) )

```py
def func(arr):
    if(len(arr)==2):
        return arr 
    elif(len(arr)==3):
        return arr[:2] if arr[0]*arr[1]<0 else arr[1:]
    else:
        i=0
        l=len(arr)
        while(arr[l//2+i]*arr[0]>0):
            i+=1
        if(l//2+i==l-1):
            for i in range(1, l//2):
                if(arr[i]*arr[i-1]<0):
                    return arr[i-1:i+1]
            return arr[-2:]
        return func(arr[:len(arr)//2+1+i])
```

Comment: That is O(N), but the questions is asking for O(log N)

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_sign_change(A):
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(A,A[1:])):
        if (x>0) - (y>0): break
    return i


print(find_sign_change([3, 4, 6,-6,-5,-3,-5]))
>>> 2
print(find_sign_change([3,-4, 6, 6, 5, 3,-5]))
>>> 0
```

Or with multiplication `(x>0) - (y>0)` can be replaced by `x*y>0`.

I don't think O(log N) is possible.